# How can I cancel a GitHub Actions workflow if the commit has no tag

Tags: github, github-actions

I have npm publish github actions, I want to run this action if my commit has tag, otherwise I don't want to run my action because of that if I do not add any tag my commit then action is run and failed because it try to publish already publish npm package with same tag. For example with my last commit I have tag `1.2.3` and my npm package was publish with `1.2.3` version. When I add new commit to my branch without any tag actions try to publish my package with `1.2.3` version tag so it failed. Here my actions code below, is there any solution for it.

Thanks for advive.

```
name: NPM Publish

on:
  push:
    branches:
    - master
    tags: 
    - v*

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build  & Publish 
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2.4.0
        with:
          node-version: 12
          registry-url: https://registry.npmjs.org/      
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm publish --access public
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.NPM_TOKEN}}
```

I need something like that on yml file

`if(git_commit has tag) continue job else stop job;`

**EDITTED VERSION**

I edit my yml file base on [@Enrico Campidoglio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26396/enrico-campidoglio) suggestion but still is does not work. I made two commit first one without tag and it canceled the action but second one has tag it still canceled action. Is there any new suggestion or solution ?

```
name: NPM Publish

on:
  push:
    branches:
    - master

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build  & Publish 
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2.4.0
        with:
          node-version: 12
          registry-url: https://registry.npmjs.org/
      - run: echo "GIT_COMMIT=`echo $(git rev-parse --short HEAD)`" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - run: echo "GIT_TAG=`echo $(git describe --tags --exact-match ${{ env.GIT_COMMIT }} || :)`" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - run: echo ${{ env.GIT_TAG }} != v*
      - run: |
          if [[ ${{ env.GIT_TAG }} == v* ]] ; then
          echo "Tag found..."
          else
          echo "No git tag found, action cancelled..."
          exit 1
          fi


      - uses: andymckay/cancel-action@0.2
        if: ${{ env.GIT_TAG }} != v*
          
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm publish --access public
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.NPM_TOKEN}}
```

there is action result I cannot figure out what is the problem,

[image]

here the lastest failed action: https://github.com/sametcelikbicak/enum2array/runs/3513521031?check_suite_focus=true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution finally after too many tried. I changed my mind and try to run `shell script` and it works :)

Just add that line in my yml file

```
      - name: Check Git Tag to continue publish
        run: ./scripts/publish.sh
```

and I created a `sh` file for control the commit tag. You can find the latest script and yml file definitions below

Here is my lastest `yml` file, `npm-publish.yml`

```
name: NPM Publish

on:
  push:
    branches:
    - master

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build  & Publish 
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2.4.0
        with:
          node-version: 12
          registry-url: https://registry.npmjs.org/

      - name: Check Git Tag to continue publish
        run: ./scripts/publish.sh
          
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm publish --access public
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.NPM_TOKEN}}
```

Here is my `script` file, `publish.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

GIT_COMMIT=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)
GIT_TAG=$(git describe --tags --exact-match $COMMIT || :)

if [[ ${GIT_TAG} == v* ]] ; then
    echo "$GIT_TAG Tag found..."
else
    echo "No git tag found, action cancelled..."
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, there isn't an official action to cancel the current workflow. There is, however, [an official GitHub API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#cancel-a-workflow-run) and [a third-party action](http://github.com/marketplace/actions/cancel-this-build) that invokes it. You could combine it with an [`if` conditional](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#example-expression-in-an-if-conditional) and the [`github` context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#github-context) to achieve what you want:

```yaml
steps:
  - uses: andymckay/cancel-action@0.2
    if: startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags')
```

Be aware that cancelling a workflow through the API is an *asynchronous* operation, which means that later steps might still get executed until the workflow runner handles the request.

A much more solid approach would be to put a condition on your publishing step to only run when the workflow was triggered by a new tag:

```yaml
steps:
  - run: npm publish --access public
    if: startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags')
    env:
      NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.NPM_TOKEN}}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I did some changes and I update my question with newly added changes but still does not work :(

Comment: Your updated workflow looks incorrect. The first step invokes the `cancel-action` without any `if` condition, which means it's always going to cancel the build.

Comment: which place or line is incorrect, could you notify that place in my latest yml file.

Comment: The `- uses: andymckay/cancel-action@0.2` line in your `yml` file needs an `if` condition. You can see it in the first example in my answer. However, I'd recommend you delete it altogether and just publish when the workflow was triggered by a tag, like you did below the `- run: npm publish --access public` line.

Comment: I guess    ```- uses: andymckay/cancel-action@0.2
        if: ${{ env.GIT_TAG }} != v*```  lines has problem, how can I  handle this control ?

Comment: Try replacing the `if` condition with `if: startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags/v')`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68777117/3736955